# How do I visualize a net in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data as data
import torchvision.models as models
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision.models.vgg import model_urls
from torchviz import make_dot

batch_size = 3
learning_rate =0.0002
epoch = 50

resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
print resnet
make_dot(resnet)
```

I want to visualize `resnet` from the pytorch models. How can I do it? I tried to use `torchviz` but it gives an error:

```
'ResNet' object has no attribute 'grad_fn'
```

Comment: Which version of PyTorch are you using?

Comment: latest from master

Comment: what about pytorch's support for tensorboard...?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `make_dot` expects a variable (i.e., tensor with `grad_fn`), not the model itself.
try:

```
x = torch.zeros(1, 3, 224, 224, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=False)
out = resnet(x)
make_dot(out)  # plot graph of variable, not of a nn.Module
```

Comment: how do I save the image as a file?

Comment: this shows what happens when we back-prop. But may I know how can I  view the front-prop?

Comment: @LukAron in what way is your forward pass different than the backward pass? The backward pass is defined by the forward pass (and the gradient chain-rule)

Comment: I believe `requires_grad=False` is incorrect. Torchviz need it to set to `True` to be able to backpropagate and tracing the network graph structure.

Answer (score 117):

Here are three different graph visualizations using different tools.

In order to generate example visualizations, I'll use a simple RNN to perform sentiment analysis taken from an [online tutorial](https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/1%20-%20Simple%20Sentiment%20Analysis.ipynb):

```py
class RNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):

        super().__init__()
        self.embedding  = nn.Embedding(input_dim, embedding_dim)
        self.rnn        = nn.RNN(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.fc         = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, text):

        embedding       = self.embedding(text)
        output, hidden  = self.rnn(embedding)

        return self.fc(hidden.squeeze(0))
```

Here is the output if you `print()` the model.

```py
RNN(
  (embedding): Embedding(25002, 100)
  (rnn): RNN(100, 256)
  (fc): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=1, bias=True)
)
```

Below are the results from three different visualization tools.

For all of them, you need to have dummy input that can pass through the model's `forward()` method. A simple way to get this input is to retrieve a batch from your Dataloader, like this:

```py
batch = next(iter(dataloader_train))
yhat = model(batch.text) # Give dummy batch to forward().
```

### Torchviz

https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz

I believe this tool generates its graph using the backwards pass, so all the boxes use the PyTorch components for back-propagation.

```py
from torchviz import make_dot

make_dot(yhat, params=dict(list(model.named_parameters()))).render("rnn_torchviz", format="png")
```

This tool produces the following output file:

[image: torchviz output]

This is the only output that clearly mentions the three layers in my model, `embedding`, `rnn`, and `fc`. The operator names are taken from the backward pass, so some of them are difficult to understand.

### HiddenLayer

https://github.com/waleedka/hiddenlayer

This tool uses the forward pass, I believe.

```py
import hiddenlayer as hl

transforms = [ hl.transforms.Prune('Constant') ] # Removes Constant nodes from graph.

graph = hl.build_graph(model, batch.text, transforms=transforms)
graph.theme = hl.graph.THEMES['blue'].copy()
graph.save('rnn_hiddenlayer', format='png')
```

Here is the output. I like the shade of blue.

[image: hiddenlayer output]

I find that the output has too much detail and obfuscates my architecture. For example, why is `unsqueeze` mentioned so many times?

### Netron

https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron

This tool is a desktop application for Mac, Windows, and Linux. It relies on the model being first exported into [ONNX format](https://onnx.ai/). The application then reads the ONNX file and renders it. There is then an option to export the model to an image file.

```py
input_names = ['Sentence']
output_names = ['yhat']
torch.onnx.export(model, batch.text, 'rnn.onnx', input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names)
```

Here's what the model looks like in the application. I think this tool is pretty slick: you can zoom and pan around, and you can drill into the layers and operators. The only negative I've found is that it only does vertical layouts.

[image: Netron screenshot]

Comment: Netron also supports horizontal layouts (see menu)

Comment: I am unable to make this work with GATConv neural nets? I get an exception in get_var_name: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'.

Comment: Netron does have an option 'Show Horizontal'. Work great for me.

Comment: Sorry, what is `batch.text`?

Comment: I think its batch data, just put a dummy batch data

Answer (score 25):

This might be a late answer. But, especially with `__torch_function__` developed, it is possible to get better visualization. You can try my project here, [torchview](https://github.com/mert-kurttutan/torchview)

For your example of resnet50, you check the colab notebook, [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/mert-kurttutan/torchview/blob/main/docs/docs/tutorial/notebook/example_vision.ipynb)
where I demonstrate visualization of resnet18 model. The image of resnet18 is produced by the following code

```
import torchvision
from torchview import draw_graph

model_graph = draw_graph(resnet18(), input_size=(1,3,224,224), expand_nested=True)
model_graph.visual_graph
```

[image: Resnet by Torchview]

It also accepts a wide range of output/input types (e.g. list, dictionary)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33142722)

Comment: @isaactfa  I tried to add images that shows the result, but I do not have high enough badges to add images. Do you have a solution for displaying the images to which I gave a link?

Comment: Code just runs but no graph appears.

Comment: Also can't access the colab notebook.

Comment: @ojunk  I  just updated the link for notebook it should work now. I also checked the code, it works fine for me.

Comment: It's working fine on Google Colab. If you want to make it work on VSCode and save it as PNG or SVG, use ```model_graph.resize_graph(scale=5.0) # scale as per the view
model_graph.visual_graph.render(format='svg') ```

Answer (score 16):

You can have a look at PyTorchViz (https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz), "A small package to create visualizations of PyTorch execution graphs and traces."

[image: Example PyTorchViz visualization]

Comment: how does one save the graph as an image?

Comment: `from graphviz import Source;`
`model_arch = make_dot(...);`
`Source(model_arch).render(filepath);`

Comment: this shows what happens when we back-prop. But may I know how can I  view the front-prop?

Comment: @CharlieParker https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz/issues/24

Answer (score 13):

Here is how you do it with `torchviz` if you want to save the image:

```
# http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/pytorch-detach.html

import torch
from torchviz import make_dot

x=torch.ones(10, requires_grad=True)
weights = {'x':x}

y=x**2
z=x**3
r=(y+z).sum()

make_dot(r).render("attached", format="png")
```

screenshot of image you get:

[image]

source: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/pytorch-detach.html

Comment: this shows what happens when we back-prop. But may I know how can I  view the front-prop?

Comment: @LukAron that is the front-prop basically...it's just those operations but its backward version.

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that actually works for my torchviz. The important part is `requires_grad=True`

Answer (score 4):

If I can shamelessly plug, I wrote a package, [TorchLens](https://github.com/johnmarktaylor91/torchlens), that can visualize a PyTorch model graph in just one line of code (it should work for any arbitrary PyTorch model, but let me know if it fails for your model).

Comment: It works nicely!. But I tried `torchvision.models.detection.fcos_resnet50_fpn()`, and it takes too much time to generate a graph (on CPU). Is there any way to generate faster?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is how I improve the package :] The visualization goes somewhat faster if you don't save any activations along the way, but for really complex models it's always going to take a bit of time (but, I'm always looking for ways to speed it up). In the meantime, if you want the visuals for that model in particular, they can be found here, in both the training and eval modes:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1uq3VNqpvaacWMKiNb1_oLR2uzSmJr9ms

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another plug: [TorchExplorer](https://github.com/spfrommer/torchexplorer) (live demo [here](https://wandb.ai/spfrom_team/torchexplorer_demo/reports/TorchExplorer-interactive-neural-network-inspection--Vmlldzo1OTUxNDQy)). It's sort of a combination of Netron and wandb.watch. It can:

- Interactively traverse model architectures, showing input/output tensor sizes and module parameters
- Visualize module input/output tensors, parameters, and associated gradients as histograms over the course of training (modeled off of wandb.watch)
- Directly integrate with weights and biases or serve standalone with a simple torchexplorer.watch call

[image]