# Save a block diagram of model in PyTorch

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

Keras has a nice functionality to save the model architecture as a block diagram

```
keras.utils.plot_model(self.model, plot_filepath.as_posix(), show_shapes=True)
```

Can this be achieved in PyTorch?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49989438/3337089) talks about printing summary similar to Keras. Is there something similar to save the block diagram of model architecture?

Comment: https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I visualize a net in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468956/how-do-i-visualize-a-net-in-pytorch)