# Torchviz doesn't show image

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to use torchviz but it's not giving any output. No error or warning either..

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torchviz import make_dot
yhat= a+b*x_train_tensor
make_dot(yhat).render("attached", format="png")
```

I also tried using `make_dot(yhat)` but that doesn't work either. In the above only a small file with the name "attached" is being created but is not an image. Obviously `x_train_tensor` and `yhat` are all tensors and compute just fine. It's the visualization that I'm having trouble with.

I have already seen these posts.

[How do I visualize a net in Pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468956/how-do-i-visualize-a-net-in-pytorch/60253769#60253769)

https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz/issues/5

But couldn't solve the problem.
I'm using python 3.7.4 64 bit in vscode

Comment: It is important however, that one of your variables requires gradient. If not there is no dependency graph which is what I think torchviz draws. For example: `x_train_tensor = torch.rand(10, requires_grad=True)`. I am unable to reproduce the error. I mean, torchviz creates an image of the graph

Comment: @BCJuan it has gradient..as I said earlier the code works fine. The gradients work properly. It's just the visualization that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why your code is not producing a `.png` without seeing the rest of it, but you could try displaying the the small file "attached" you mention.  It is a  `.dot` file.  Rename it to `something.dot.`  See this post for example [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494492/graphviz-how-to-go-from-dot-to-a-graphf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494492/graphviz-how-to-go-from-dot-to-a-graph) for how to display a `.dot` file.