# How to generate the architectural figure of the network in pytorch when the type of the output of the network is list?

Tags: python, pytorch

I wonder how to use tochviz to generate network architecture, when the output is a list type?
the demo code is as follows:

```py
 import torch
 import torch.nn as nn
 class ConvNet(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self):
         super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
         self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, 1, 1),
             nn.ReLU(),
             nn.AvgPool2d(2, 2)
         )
         self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, 1, 1),
             nn.ReLU(),
             nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
         )
         self.fc = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 7, 128),
             nn.ReLU(),
             nn.Linear(128, 64),
             nn.ReLU()
         )
         self.out = nn.Linear(64, 10)
     def forward(self, x):
         x = self.conv1(x)
         x = self.conv2(x)
         x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
         x = self.fc(x)
         output = []
         output.append(x)
         output.append(self.out(x))
         return output
 MyConvNet = ConvNet()
```

and I use `torchviz` to view this network's architecture like

```py
 from torchviz import make_dot
 x = torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28).requires_grad_(True)
 y = MyConvNet(x)   
 MyConvNetVis = make_dot(y, params=dict(list(MyConvNet.named_parameters()) + [('x', x)]))
 MyConvNetVis.format = "png"
 MyConvNetVis.directory = "data"
 MyConvNetVis.view()
```

then, I was blocked with this problem

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-c8e3cd3a8b4e> in <module>
      2 x = torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28).requires_grad_(True)
      3 y = MyConvNet(x)
----> 4 MyConvNetVis = make_dot(y, params=dict(list(MyConvNet.named_parameters()) + [('x', x)]))
      5 MyConvNetVis.format = "png"
      6 MyConvNetVis.directory = "data"

~/anaconda3/envs/torch1.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchviz/dot.py in make_dot(var, params)
     35         return '(' + (', ').join(['%d' % v for v in size]) + ')'
     36 
---> 37     output_nodes = (var.grad_fn,) if not isinstance(var, tuple) else tuple(v.grad_fn for v in var)
     38 
     39     def add_nodes(var):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'grad_fn'
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates `torchviz` is trying to navigate through the network using `grad_fn` in order to compute its own graph. However, a *tuple* is not a *tensor* and doesn't have the `gra_fn` property.
I'm not quite sure you can have multiple outputs (i.e. a *tuple* as output) when working with `torchviz`. As a workaround, if you just want to visualize the network you could replace the *tuple* with concatenation of the two tensors using [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html):

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.fc(x)
    out = self.out(x)
    output = torch.cat([x, out], dim=1)
    return output
```

The result is:

[image]

Notice how the last node is a `CatBackward` with two incoming branches, one from `AddmmBackward` (`out`) and the other from `ReluBackward0` (`x`). This last node is fictitious and is not present in your actual model, so you could remove it from the graph, *by hand*.

Comment: hi, **I'm not quite sure you can have multiple outputs (i.e. a tuple as output) when working with torchviz.`** frankly to say, it doesn't work when the output is a tuple. I tried many tricks to tackle this problem, and finally ToT nonetheless. Anyway, a great solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468956/how-do-i-visualize-a-net-in-pytorch) shows packages that can build the architectural diagram/graph for a Pytorch Model:

- torchviz/pytorchviz
- TensorBoard
- Netron
- HiddenLayer