# Is my model using dropout although it is not in the forward pass ? Printing the model shows only the attributes

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have the following nn model in pytorch, the forward method is not using dropout, but there is an instance of dropout in the class, and it gets printed when the class is instantiated. Is the model using dropout or not?
Here is the code structure.

```
n_input_dim=train_ds[0][0].shape[0] #getting the input dimension of a sample
n_hidden1, n_hidden2, n_hidden3, n_hidden4, n_output =[1048, 724, 324, 121, 1]

class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1=nn.Linear(n_input_dim, n_hidden1)
        self.layer2=nn.Linear(n_hidden1, n_hidden2)
        self.layer3=nn.Linear(n_hidden2, n_hidden3)
        self.layer4=nn.Linear(n_hidden3, n_hidden4)
        self.layer_out=nn.Linear(n_hidden4, n_output)
        self.relu=nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout=nn.Dropout(p=0.5)


    def forward(self, inputs):
        x=self.relu(self.layer1(inputs))
        x=self.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x=self.relu(self.layer3(x))
        x=self.relu(self.layer4(x))
        x=self.layer_out(x)
        return x

learning_rate=0.01
epochs=300
loss_func=nn.L1Loss()
model=NN()
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
print(model)
```

```
NN(
  (layer1): Linear(in_features=1125, out_features=1048, bias=True)
  (layer2): Linear(in_features=1048, out_features=524, bias=True)
  (layer3): Linear(in_features=524, out_features=262, bias=True)
  (layer4): Linear(in_features=262, out_features=131, bias=True)
  (layer_out): Linear(in_features=131, out_features=1, bias=True)
  (relu): ReLU()
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
)
```

I tried to use adding dropout in the forward function, but it printed the same.

Comment: the dropout variable is not being used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The dropout layer is registered as a submodule of the `NN` module, and as a result is printed when you print the model. However, it is not being called anywhere (in particular, including the forward pass), so in a conceptual sense your network does not have a dropout layer since it is not being used.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It clarified my doubt. Can you please let me know how to get the nn structure which is used in training then?

Comment: @D_M [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458882/5987698) might help.