Create a graph from Pytorch Module
Let's assume we have a Pytorch model as follows (I intentionally made the model complex with branch so that it covers all corner cases).
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ComplexNetWithBranch, self).__init__()
        
        # Common layers before branching
        self.seq = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(10, 20),
            torch.nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        self.inner_seq_1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(15, 15),
            torch.nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.inner_seq_2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(15, 15),
            torch.nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        # Branch 1
        self.branch1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(20, 15),
            self.inner_seq_1,
            self.inner_seq_2
        )
        
        # Branch 2
        self.branch2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(20, 15),
            torch.nn.ReLU()
        )
        
        # Common layers after recombining
        self.fc_combine = torch.nn.Linear(30, 10)
        self.fc_output = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)
        
        # ModuleList after recombination
        self.module_list = torch.nn.ModuleList([
            torch.nn.Linear(1, 5),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Linear(5, 1)
        ])

    def forward(self, x):
        # Common forward pass before branching
        x = self.seq(x)
        
        # Branching
        branch1_out = self.branch1(x)
        branch2_out = self.branch2(x)
        
        # Concatenate the outputs of both branches
        x = torch.cat([branch1_out, branch2_out], dim=1)
        
        # Pass through the combined layer
        x = self.fc_combine(x)
        x = self.fc_output(x)
        
        # ModuleList forward pass
        for layer in self.module_list:
            x = layer(x)
        
        return x

Now I want to implement a function that returns a nx graph.
def module_to_graph(module: torch.nn.Module) -> nx.DiGraph:
    pass

The graph should have all the nodes (MyModel, seq, inner_seq_1, branch1, and everything inside). Let's say the id/name of the nodes will be something like this "MyModel_seq_0" or "MyModel_branch1_1_0". There will be edges for the data flow, and a way (as node attribute or as edge with an attribute) to determine which node is wrapping which node.
There is a similar question without any answer. So, I am posting this with a more specific structure.

I am not very familiar with NetworkX but I imagine you can recursively iterate through the children of your root nn.Module using the method named_children. See documentation here : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_children
Then it is just a matter of iterating over all subchildren and building you nx graph as you go

@trialNerror, yes, it is possible to get the structure of the model, but this way wont give you the data flow for all the modules.

This question is maybe of interest:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468956/how-do-i-visualize-a-net-in-pytorch
